# Vertical Alignment Centered with Landscape Orientation problem in Bootstrap 4.1

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

In **landscape orientation** I have problem with my v**ertical alignment centralized (card in the center of the screen)**, it cuts various information like my image (logo) ...

The **"problem"** is in the `h-100` of the **MAIN tag**, the **CONTAINER** and the **ROW** ..

But I do not know why of the problem in this kind of orientation, since I'm following the bootstrap documentation, the only way I know to fix this is with **@media queries**, however this will **"bug"** the other **resolutions of notebooks and computers**. ..

**What should I do and why does this problem occur?**

**CSS:**

```
html,
body { height: 100%; }
```

**HTML:**

```
<main class="h-100">
    <div class="container h-100">
        <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center h-100">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="card mx-auto d-block shadow-md-large w-md-80 w-lg-50">
                    <div class="card-header bg-transparent border-0 py-md-5">
                        <img src="/img/logo/aliansce_full.svg" alt="Aliansce Shopping Centers" class="CLI img-fluid mx-auto d-block" autocomplete="on" autofocus require>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body px-md-5">
                        <form autocomplete="on">
                            <div class="form-group EGLF mt-4 mt-md-0">
                                <input type="text" id="FLUI" class="form-control FI EFLI border-top-0 border-right-0 border-left-0 rounded-0 shadow-none" autocomplete="on" autofocus required>
                                <!-- FLOAT LABEL EFFECT -->
                                <label fo="FLUI" id="FLUL" class="EFL">Usuário</label>
                                <span class="EFHL"></span>
                                <span class="EFBL"></span>
                                <!-- FRONTEND RESPONSE ERROR MESSAGE -->
                                <div id="FBMEU" class="FBMEU ml-1 text-danger"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group EGLF mt-4">
                                <input type="password" id="FLUPI" class="form-control FI EFLI border-top-0 border-right-0 border-left-0 rounded-0 shadow-none" min="1" maxlength="10" required>
                                <!-- FLOAT LABEL EFFECT -->
                                <label for="FLUPI" id="FLUPL" class="EFL">Senha</label>
                                <span class="EFHL"></span>
                                <span class="EFBL"></span>
                                <!-- FRONTEND RESPONSE ERROR MESSAGE -->
                                <div id="FBMEUP" class="ml-1 text-danger"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group mt-5">
                                <button type="button" id="FBSL" class="btn btn-primary w-esm-100 mb-2 px-lg-5">LOGIN</button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn bg-light w-esm-100 px-lg-5">VOLTAR</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                        <!-- BACKEND RESPONSE ERROR MESSAGE -->
                        <div class="text-center text-danger">
                            Usuário ou senha incorretos.
                            <br> Caso esteja com dificuldades, clique em "Precisa de Ajuda?".
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer bg-white border-0">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-link mx-auto d-block">Precisa de Ajuda?</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I think the issue is that the card itself is simply too big to fit appropriately in the smaller screen, can you replicate the issue in a fiddle?

Comment: Could you explain why you use `h-100` for the main, body, and html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to align the card in the center of both axis. If so, this might solve your issue.

---

Using grid layout is unnecessary since you have only one `card`. Furthermore, you should better not change the `display` of `card`. Let is be as it is.

---

Use the following classes on  `main` element

- `d-flex`
- `flex-column` to change its direction so that its content maintain its intrinsic properties such as `width`.
- Since its direction is now `column`, use `justify-content-center` to align its content **vertically** in the center. Otherwise, you would have used `align-items-center`.

---

Add a new `d-flex` element and use `justify-content-center` on it to align its content **horizontally** in the center.

---

Add an another `block` element and use `w-md-80 w-lg-50` on it.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jQQrog